# Cannot port forward with Aztech router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding

**Pre-conditions:**

1. Laptop connected to Aztech DSL5018EN router via Wi-Fi
2. DHCP with MAC-IP Reservation
3. Router firewall disabled
4. Windows 7 Firewall with Inbound Rule for port 8080 (TCP/UDP)
5. Microsoft Security Essentials in default settings
6. Tomcat running on port 8080

[image]

[image]

[image]

What could be going wrong with my configurations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was wrong with my settings. My local ISP issues a private IP to non-commercial subscriber lines so no port forwarding will ever work.